# Sqlite Call to a member function bindParam() on boolean

Tags: php, sqlite, pdo

Hello I try with PDO to insert data to Sqlite, i have tried many ways, but I always get following errors: Call to a member function bindParam() on boolean.

I see also the bindParam() or bindValue return false if an error exist. But I don't find an error.

thx in advance

```
    function insertCostumers(){
    $costumers = 'INSERT IGNORE INTO costumers(first_name,last_name,age)
            VALUES(:first_name,:last_name,:age)';
    $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare($costumers);
    $data = [['firstName' => 'Hans',
            'lastName' => 'Meier',
            'age' => 32],
            ['firstName' => 'Anna',
            'lastName' => 'Mueller',
            'age' => 35],
            ['firstName' => 'Steffi',
            'lastName' => 'Gygax',
            'age' => 67]];

        $stmt->bindParam(
            ':first_name', $firstName,
            ':last_name', $lastName,
            'age', $age);
        foreach ($data as $d) {
             // Set values to bound variables
            $firstName = $d['firstName'];
            $lastName = $d['lastName'];
            $age = $d['age'];
            // Execute statement
            $stmt->execute();
        }
        die('hello');
}


require "SQLiteConnection.php";
require "SQLiteCreateTable.php";

$sqlite = new SQLiteCreateTable((new SQLiteConnection())->connect());
// create new tables
$sqlite->createTables();
$sqlite->insertCostumers();
$tables = $sqlite->getOrderList();
require "index.view.php";
```

@SebastianBrosch Thats the Create Statement.

```
public function createTables() {
$commands = ['CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS costumers (
                costumer_id integer PRIMARY KEY,
                first_name text NOT NULL,
                last_name text NOT NULL,
                age integer NOT NULL
              )',
    'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS orders (
            order_id integer PRIMARY KEY,
            order_nr integer NOT NULL,
            costumer_id integer,
            FOREIGN KEY (costumer_id) REFERENCES costumers (costumer_id) 
            ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE NO ACTION)'];
     // execute the sql commands to create new tables
     foreach ($commands as $command) {
        $this->pdo->exec($command);
     }

}
```

Comment: So, you have to find error text. It is described in a manual, open it and read.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The variable `$stmt` is not a [`PDOStatement`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/class.pdostatement.php) object. It is a boolean value (in this case `false`).

Your [`INSERT`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_insert.html) statement is not valid. Try the following instead (missing `OR`):

```
$costumers = 'INSERT OR IGNORE INTO costumers(first_name, last_name, age)
        VALUES(:first_name, :last_name, :age)';
```

You can use the methods [`PDO::errorInfo`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.errorinfo.php) and [`PDO::errorCode`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.errorcode.php) to get further information.

```
$costumers = 'INSERT OR IGNORE INTO costumers(first_name,last_name,age)
        VALUES(:first_name,:last_name,:age)';
$stmt = $this->pdo->prepare($costumers);

if ($stmt === false) {
     echo $this->pdo->errorCode().': '.$this->pdo->errorInfo();
}
```

You also use `$firstName` and `$lastName` before init:

```
function insertCostumers() {
    $costumers = 'INSERT OR IGNORE INTO costumers(first_name, last_name, age)
        VALUES(:first_name, :last_name, :age)';
    $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare($costumers);
    $data = [['firstName' => 'Hans',
        'lastName' => 'Meier',
        'age' => 32],
        ['firstName' => 'Anna',
        'lastName' => 'Mueller',
        'age' => 35],
        ['firstName' => 'Steffi',
        'lastName' => 'Gygax',
        'age' => 67]];

     foreach ($data as $d) {
         $firstName = $d['firstName'];
         $lastName = $d['lastName'];
         $age = $d['age'];

         $stmt->bindParam(':first_name', $firstName, PDO::PARAM_STR);
         $stmt->bindParam(':last_name', $lastName, PDO::PARAM_STR);
         $stmt->bindParam(':age', $age, PDO::PARAM_INT);

        $stmt->execute();
    }
}
```

---

To make sure the combination of `first_name` and `last_name` is unique, you need to add a `UNIQUE` constraint to your table `costumers`. Use the following [`CREATE TABLE`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html) statement:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS costumers (
    costumer_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    first_name TEXT NOT NULL,
    last_name TEXT NOT NULL,
    age INTEGER NOT NULL,
    UNIQUE (first_name, last_name)
);
```

> You can see the difference with and without the `UNIQUE` constraint on these following demo:
>   http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/79b1c/1/1

Comment: thx Sebastian thats fine working, but now i have the Problem that the records are multipli in the Database.

Comment: @AnasSyed - can you show the `CREATE TABLE` statement of `costumers`?

Comment: I post the Create Statement